# How to get the maximum value and the position from each row of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Assume that I have a matrix like this `A=np.array([[1,2,3],[5,2,6],[7,1,5]])`

Then, I want to select the biggest value and the position from each row.

The result should be Value=[3,6,7], Position=[2,2,0].

In Matlab, the code `[Value,Position]=max(A);` can calculate the correct answer

But I need to change it into Python code.

I have ever tried the code like that

```
Value=np.max(A, axis=1)
Position=np.where(A==np.max(A,axis=1)) 

Result:
Value=array([3, 6, 7])
Position=(array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32))
```

The biggest value is correct, but the position is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `argmax`, and use the result to index your into your array.

```
idx = A.argmax(axis=1)
val = A[np.arange(len(A)), idx]
```

```
idx
array([2, 2, 0])    

val
array([3, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ^_^